# Linux shared folder with manager user on them

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I have a /ftp directory. And inside it, a subdirectory of different users.

```
/ftp/max
/ftp/alex
/ftp/arturo
/ftp/paco
```

I need that every user, can only read, write, execute, inside his directory. Nothing else (this part I can do it with chroot every user inside these folders)

Now, I need a user, eg: marketing. Who will be able to read, write, execute everything inside all of those users, without being root?

How should I manage this?
I thought about making a group eg: shared, and set `chown -R :shared /ftp` && `chmod -R g+s /ftp` so all the files created inside /ftp will be with shared group owner.

And then marketing inside that group?

Comment: If you are planning to access this with ftp and only ftp, there are ftp daemons that can be configured to handle scenarios like this.

Comment: @mzedeler Yes, this will be accesible from Windows with filezilla. All this is with Samba on Linux

Answer (score 1):

Check **Access Control Lists (ACL)** - it provides an additional, more flexible permission mechanism for file systems. It is designed to assist with UNIX file permissions. ACL allows you to give permissions for any user or **group** to any disc resource.

You can add group name "somegroup" with r-x permissions on a folder with a command:

```
setfacl -m g:somegroup:r-x /path/to/folder
```

You can check what are ACLs of the folder with:

```
getfacl /path/to/folder
```